# Getting "Access Denied" message on ADF faces page

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have deployed a sample application on weblogic server 12c, it is deployed successfully but the page doesn't show any table data, instead a message "Access denied" is displayed on the page.

[image]

Comment: did this ever work in testing? Have you confirmed the WLS data connection pool is configured and you're using that for your AM?Did you change the AM to use the WLS datasource?  LOTS of things here you have not told us.

Comment: Yes, I have tested with AM tester, it works fine with AM tester, the error is displayed in the browser

Comment: no, i meant did you test the ADF Faces PAGE before you deployed.

Comment: Yes, I have tested the page, it workig fine. The page has adf table, page is showing coloumn headers/title, but no data shown, instead "Access denied" message shown

Answer (score 0):

OK, after reading some community blogs, I have placed(wrapped) the ADF table in a panel, now it is working fine, showing results from the table. Previously I was placing Adf table directly to the page without panel.

Answer (score 0):

After dragging the table to the jsf page , go to structures , choose -> Surround with , select Panel box/Panel form layout from the options .

Run the page.
Done.

(Works with 11g,12c)